# Installing MonoGame_3.0.1.mpack in XamarinStudio in Mac OS x I got this error "The Packacge 'Core v4.0' could not be found in any repository"

Tags: iphone, macos, monogame, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to configure my development environment in my Mac with Xamarin and MonoGame but when I tried to add "MonoGame_3.0.1.mpack" in the Add-in Manager I got this error:

```
The Packacge 'Core v4.0' could not be found in any repository
The Packacge 'Ide v4.0' could not be found in any repository
```

[image: xamarin error]

This what I have installed on my Mac with no errors:

-Installed XamarinStudio
-Installed MonoFramework-MDK-3.8.0.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg 
-Installed MonoFramework-MRE-3.8.0.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg

I'll really appreciate if any of you knows how can install MonoGame_3.0.1.mpack in Xamarin on Mac OS x

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that that version of the template is not compatible with the version of Xamarian Studio you have installed. Until the newest version of Xamarian Studio is released for Mac, you won't be able to install that template.

However, you can [download the template](https://github.com/stebyrne04/Monogame_templates/raw/master/MonoDevelop.MonoGame_3.2.0.2.mpack) from [here](https://github.com/stebyrne04/Monogame_templates/blob/master/M). It is compatible with the Mac OS X build version 5.5.2 of Xamarian Studio.